# Java Text File not able to be read

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to read in a text file and create an array of objects. I keep getting the following error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Prog6.main(Prog6.java:33)
```

Its not reading the fields and i've tried everything I can think of to fix it. Here is the code. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Prog6
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fname;
    String lname;
    String team; 
    String position;
    int completions;
    int attempts;
    int yards; 
    int receptions;

    Scanner inFile = null;
    Report rep = new Report();

    /*
     * Open File
     */
    try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner( new File( "nfl.txt" ) );
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        System.err.println( "Error: file not found" );
    }
    /*
     * Read file
     */

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        fname = inFile.next();
        lname = inFile.next();
        team = inFile.next();
        position = inFile.next();
        if (position == "QB")
        {
            completions = inFile.nextInt();
            attempts = inFile.nextInt();
            yards = inFile.nextInt();
            Player qb = new Player ();

            rep.addQuarterback(qb);
        }
        else if (position == "WR")
        {
            receptions = inFile.nextInt();
            yards = inFile.nextInt();
            Player wr = new Player ();

            rep.addReceiver(wr);
        }

        // Print report

        rep.printReport();      
    }


}
}
```

Comment: How does nfl.txt look like?

Comment: *"Any advice would be appreciated. ..`Prog6.main(Prog6.java:33)`"*  Look at line 33 of `Prog6.java` and add a comment at the end of line saying something like `// this is where it fails!`.  Now you have identified that line, try printing the value of whatever objects(s) are referenced in it.

Comment: Every part of the code after the `catch` should be inside the `try`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason there's a line being read in that doesn't have as many items as you think it does.  The scanner has a set of hasNext methods (like hasNextLong() for long values) that tell you whether there's a next item to be scanned and whether the item is of the correct format.  Use those methods before getting the next item and you can avoid the error.

Comment: Could also please mention the `String` comparison problems while you at it, so we don't get a second question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the "While" loop where you're trying to read the inFile within the "try" loop.

If I am not wrong, the file gets closed after this, so you can't really call the scanner on it.

So, you'd go:

```
try {
     inFile = new Scanner(new File("nfl.txt"));        
     while(inFile.hasNext()) {    
         .....      
         ..... 
} catch
```